# Linux installer keeps freezing, unable to install any Linux

Tags: system-installation

I tried both Ubuntu 18 and Linux Mint 19, both freeze and cannot install a Linux. Apparently, there is an Ubuntu 18 installed somewhere(despite not booting into any OS) and it keeps notifying me that my disk is full (not true, but it shows me some 7gb root partition on smth). Booting from live USB.

**EDIT**: It’s a bit of a long story but I will do my best as a beginner to explain everything. I had Ubuntu 17 and decided to upgrade it to 18 via the command line command, after the update there was a weird bug which I couldn’t fix despite looking for days on the internet. This weird bug was that after pressing enter on the login screen, ubuntu 18.04 would freeze completely. So I tried reinstalling it, which failed since it kept freezing at different times (booting from liveUSB).

I  restarted so many times (in hope of the installer to work) that the previous os got corrupted. That’s when I decided to switch to a different Linux distribution: Linux Mint. The same thing happened, except now I got a different message: `low disk space 0bytes remaining`.(note: I don’t have an OS, so I fully boot from live USB). So I installed windows, to delete partitions, but it was weird since I have an SSD of 256GB and only 238GB of maximum capacity was shown. Anyway, after this, I tried Linux installation 2 times, without and with liveUSB, but it failed with the same “no space” remaining message. Now I don’t have an OS, and booting from liveUSB (currently containing mint).

```
$ df -hT
Filesystem     Type      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev           devtmpfs  1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs          tmpfs     383M  1.5M  382M   1% /run
/dev/sdb1      vfat      116G  1.9G  114G   2% /cdrom
/dev/loop0     squashfs  1.8G  1.8G     0 100% /rofs
/cow           overlay   1.9G  1.8G  149M  93% /
tmpfs          tmpfs     1.9G   24M  1.9G   2% /dev/shm
tmpfs          tmpfs     5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs          tmpfs     1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs          tmpfs     1.9G  4.0K  1.9G   1% /tmp
tmpfs          tmpfs     383M   44K  383M   1% /run/user/999
tmpfs          tmpfs     383M     0  383M   0% /run/user/0

$ fdisk -l
Disk /dev/loop0: 1.7 GiB, 1859526656 bytes, 3631888 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/sda: 238.5 GiB, 256060514304 bytes, 500118192 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 7146433C-9F18-4CD5-A424-7F6665C88C41

Device       Start       End   Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sda1     2048   1050623   1048576  512M EFI System
/dev/sda2  1050624 500117503 499066880  238G Linux filesystem


Disk /dev/sdb: 115.5 GiB, 124017180672 bytes, 242221056 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x029c3084

Device     Boot Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1  *     2048 242221055 242219008 115.5G  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)
```

Comment: Hello. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Unlike other forums, we ask that you please don't put solutions in the question because we hope that multiple answers below will cover more than one possible cause of the symptoms you mention. If newcomers have the same problem but for a different reason, we don't want them to think that that's the only solution they'll find here when another answer might help their situation instead. Accepting an answer with a checkmark (as you did) avoids that problem: it puts the answer that worked for you on top while still letting newcomers see if there are other solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the Asus X541U (same model in your other question), someone reported having to add `pcie_aspm=off` to the grub settings, this was confirmed by another user with U541 [here](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2347139)

Quoting https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2303880&p=13418305#post13418305:

> When trying to install, at the initial 'grub' screen that asks you to select (1) Try Ubuntu (2) Install directly (3) OEM install etc. Place the selector over option 1 and press the letter “e” to edit the grub boot command. On the third line just after “quiet splash”add the string “pcie_aspm=off” and press F10 to continue the boot. This will allow you to start 15.10 from a USB/DVD and install to disk.

If the above is too difficult for you, you can try booting into live cd, then delete all existing partitions on your system (using GParted) before installing either 1) Windows again, or 2) an older version of Ubuntu such as 16.04 (in case your hardware has a problem specific to 18.04). 256GB reading as 238GB is perfectly normal since you don't actually get 256GB, but only 256GBits.

**Update**: The asker went with an install of Ubuntu 16.04 (likely due to some config issue while installing Ubuntu 18.04 on his hardware - Asus X541U). Having at least a working installation of Windows is highly recommended for beginners when their hardware needs some slight modification/tweak to get Ubuntu to work, since they will continue to have a working system while trying to fix Ubuntu on a dual boot. With some basic understanding of partitions, dual boot isn't much more difficult than a regular install (just shrink the Windows partition, and use freed up space for the Linux partition).

Comment: it still froze , in the “something else” option the following partitions were shown : /dev/sda; free space 1MB ; /dev/sda1 efi 536MB 33MB ; /dev/sda2 ext4 255522MB 5147MB ; free space 0 MB

Comment: @gameerik /dev/sda1 is the partition used for EFI, you need to install the OS to /dev/sda2 (and make sure you are booting in UEFI mode when starting the installer from usb etc). If you cannot make sense of that, just install Windows again, and run Linux as a virtual machine using VirtualBox etc. You can get the images from https://www.osboxes.org/ubuntu/

Comment: I understand , but my installer keeps freezing which prevents me from doing that , and I’m not really a fan of virtual machines or dual booting . (UEFI boot is enabled in bios)

Comment: @gameerik just bring the machine to IT and ask for a system reset to Windows. If you really want to use a Linux installer, download the one for 16.04 and try that instead